# Symfony 2 - When and why does a route parameter get automatically converted?

Tags: symfony

I have this route:

```
pfs_platform_home:
path:      /{page}/{reset}
defaults:  { _controller: PFSPlatformBundle:Advert:index, page: 1, reset: true }
requirements:
    page: \d*
    reset: true|false
```

If I use a link without specifying anything for *reset*, the router uses the default value and in my indexAction, the *reset* parameter is automatically converted to Boolean *true*.
i.e.:

```
<li><a href="{{ path('pfs_platform_home') }}">Inicio</a></li>
```

But when I do that, this time $reset appears as a string 'false' in my indexAction, not a Boolean:

```
<a href="{{ path('pfs_platform_home', {'page': p, 'reset': 'false'}) }}">{{ p }}</a>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So what is the generated url for the first case?

Comment: `'false'` is the string "true", `true` (without the apostrophes) is a boolean.

Comment: Like Qoop said use: ```<a href="{{ path('pfs_platform_home', {'page': p, 'reset': false}) }}">{{ p }}</a>``` false without quotes

Comment: @Chausser  Without the quotes (that was the first thing I tried), I got an error. I can't test right now to tell you which, but I'm sure it didn't work.

Comment: Try it again when you can, and post the error. It should work that way.

Comment: I bet 10 (virtual) bucks that the error message is something like `Parameter "reset" for route "pfs_platform_home" must match "true|false" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL`. Explaination see below.

Comment: @ Chausser This is the error I get: `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "reset" for route "pfs_platform_home" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL."`  (I've removed the true|false requirement, which I had added after I got this error for the first time). It looks like an empty string is being sent. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL paths and parameters are always strings. If you have an URL like

```
http://example.com/page/true?foo=2&bar=false
```

the server cannot know that the `true` should be interpreted as boolean, while `foo` is supposed to be an integer and `bar` is supposed to be boolean, too.

If you want to process URL parameters, always pass and treat them as strings.

Later, you can validate them (e.g. `is_numeric` will tell you if a string represents a number) or transform them to other types.

What you're also experiencing here is YAML's handling of unquoted strings:

- Strings may generally be left unquoted, if they don't contain a character that has a meaning in YAML.
- But: `true` in YAML is *boolean* true. Therefore, your default `reset: true` is indeed a boolean value. Declare it as `reset: "true"` and it should work. The `reset: true|false` should be fine, IMO (didn't test it, but this is treated as a regex, so it should be interpreted as string.)

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. What surprised me was that if on one side I can get a boolean, why isn't it possible on the other?  I thought EITHER my default boolean true would be converted to a string, so all parameters are strings, OR I would be able to send an actual boolean instead of the string 'false' from the twig view.  I guess the explanation comes from the fact that in the first case the route is generated on the server side, and in the second case, my request comes from the client and must be a string. Still, this behavior seems weird to me.

Comment: “… in the first case the route is generated on the server side, and in the second case, my request comes from the client and must be a string.” ← exactly. In the first case, no value is passed, so the default is boolean `true`. In the second case, a string is embedded into an HTML page, and the `{reset}` URL part is populated from the link clicked/loaded in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You have already set the defaults for your params:

```
pfs_platform_home:
path:      /{page}/{reset}
defaults:  { _controller: PFSPlatformBundle:Advert:index, page: 1, reset: true }
requirements:
    page: \d*
    reset: true|false
```

Check out `defaults:` line it says if you do not supplu `page` it will be `1` and if you do not supply value for `reset` it will default to `true`.